# Сохранение двойного графика

Tags: python, matplotlib

Строю график из двух окошек верхнего и нижнего. Но не получается сохранить все в одной картинке там где `plt.savefig('saved.png', dpi = 1000)`. Как исправить код чтобы работало и сохранялась картинка обоих графиков в одном файле нужного размера?

Возможно я вообще не правильно сделал графики и можно проще сделать, не через эти странности с  `subplot2grid((3,3),(0,0),colspan = 4)`

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 14))

a1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(0,0),colspan = 4)
plt.grid(True)

a2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(1,0),colspan = 4)
plt.grid(True)

a1.plot(arg)
a2.plot(arg)

plt.show()

plt.savefig('saved.png', dpi = 1000)
```

Comment: воспользуйтесь ООП-интерфейсом matplotlib, стройте графики на _одной_ фигуре но на разных холстах https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Много разных вариантов есть:
Вариант 1.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Линейная зависимость
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y1 = x
y2 = y1**2

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 14))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(x, y1)               
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(x, y2)
```

Вариант 2.

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(2,1)
ax[0].plot(x, y1)
ax[1].plot(x, y1)
```

Ну, и если надо сохранить,  то общее завершение

```
plt.savefig('saved.png', dpi = 1000)
```